# What's the difference between $(...) and `...` in Bash

Tags: bash

I got expected result with `...`, but failed with $(...)

```
kill $(ps ux | grep S..\.tcl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')

Illegal variable name.

kill `ps ux | grep S..\.tcl | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

(kill expected processes)
```

By googling, I found some says they are interchangable, but it is not by this example. So, What's the difference between $(...) and `...` in Bash?

Comment: I don't get that error when I run your above command it should work as written with $().

Comment: I don't get the error either.  One possibility is that the script is not actually running under bash.  Can you provide details on what OS you are using, how you are executing the script, and the shell version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a

```
grep -al 'Illegal variable name' /bin/*
```

and found the message in /bin/csh.  Looks like you are running **csh** not bash when you are giving the command. eg:

```
csh $ echo `echo abc`
abc
csh $ echo $(echo abc)
Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `csh` is not a bourne shell! Its quoting rules and related functionality is *completely* different. If you're using csh, don't expect things to work the way they work in bash (or, for that matter, to work at all; `csh` is pretty horrible)

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot! I don't know why I tested them in csh/tcsh and I didn't found that. In addition, I didn't know the output string in shell can be found with grep.

Answer (score -1):

Some explanation about the backtick ( ` ) also called command substitution:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708549/whats-the-difference-between-command-and-command-in-shell-programming

In bash (git-bash) I also obtain different results.  Running a script in a file, say /c/pathToScript/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
WORK_DIR=/c/myWorkingDirPath;
cd $WORK_DIR;
if [ `pwd` != $WORK_DIR ]; then
  echo "Oh my... "; # `pwd` returns /c/pathToScript 
fi
if [ $(pwd) != $WORK_DIR ]; then
  echo "Thank Goodness... "; #$(pwd) returns /c/myWorkingDirPath
fi
```

The $(pwd) works in the subshell created when I run the process.